# How to compute a double integral

Tags: real-analysis

I had one course of my Analysis III course and I'm already supposed to complete a problemsheet:

I would like to know the big lines to compute the following double integral:

$$\int_D f(x,y) dx\,dy$$ 
where $D = \{ x,y \in \mathbb{R^2}, x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}$ and $f(x,y) = (x+y)^2$.

Comment: Could you provide some context, like what you've attempted so far, what you've covered in the class, etc.?

Comment: I don't remember "big lines" in integration in multivariate calculus. Perhaps that is just the way your professor likes to teach it. This is the sort of thing that we can help better with if you explain more about what you have been taught.

Comment: To my knowledge, the correct English expression for "spiegazione a grandi linee" is "sketch of [proof/explanation]" or "hint", depending on how in depth you want it. Typically, "hint" is the starting idea, while "sketch of proof" is a more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the cartesian coordinates note that the domain $D$ is the circle with center at the origin and radius $1$. So the limits of integration are $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\le y \le \sqrt{1-x^2} $ for $-1 \le x\le 1$.
and the integral becomes:
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (x+y)^2 dy dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

With polar coordinates this is much easier: put $x=rcos(\varphi)$ and $y=rsin(\varphi)$, Then $r$ runs from $0$ to $1$ and $\varphi$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$. The absolute value of the Jacobian $|J(r,\varphi)|=r$. Hence the integral equals:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r(rcos(\varphi) + rsin(\varphi))^2drd\varphi=(\int_0^1r^3dr)\cdot(\int_0^{2\pi}(cos(\varphi)+sin(\varphi))^2d\varphi)=[\frac{1}{4}r^4]_0^1 \cdot \int_0^{2\pi}(1+sin(2\varphi))d\varphi=\frac{1}{4}\cdot [\varphi - \frac{1}{2}cos(2\varphi)]_0^{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2}\pi.$$